# CHSH inequality vs. Tsirelson's inequality

Tags: quantum-information, bells-inequality

CHSH inequality says that given four classical observables $a$, $a’$, $b$ and $b’$, the observable

$$C= ab + a’b +ab’ - a’b’$$

satisfies at most

$$| \langle C \rangle | = 2$$

if we choose the “best strategy”, i.e. if we choose good observables $a$, $a’$, $b$ and $b’$. The expected value $\langle \cdot \rangle$ here means average over an ensemble of possible states. On the other hand, for quantum observables, Tsirelson's inequality reads,

$$| \langle C \rangle | \leq 2 \sqrt{2}. $$

Here, for the equality to be reached, we need not only to choose the best observables, but also have the best situation possible (the best state $| \psi \rangle$).

*Question:* why this difference? Why for the CHSH we consider all possible “realities” while for the Tsirelson's inequality we consider only the best reality?

Comment: To reach |<C>|=2 clasically we must choose the right observables and probability distribution. To reach the |<C>|<=2*sqrt(2) quantumly we must choose the right observables and the right quantum state, which yet again yields a probability distribution.  I fail to see the difference which you talk about.

Comment: Well in the first case you're choosing the right probability distribution, i.e. an ensemble of possible states. In the second case you are choosing a particular state (no ensemble). You still have a probability distribution in the measurements because of quantum mechanics, but you have no probability distribution for the state itself (the density matrix is just the projector onto the chosen state).

Comment: So what? Pure states also give a probability distribution - just that it is extremal in a certain sense (namely in the set of distributions obtained from density operators).  But the same is true for the LHV model with |<c>|=2 -- it will also be extremal in the set of LHV distributions, a generic distribution will have |<C>|<2.  (Note that you can go to a higher-dimensional space where the extremal quantum states will NOT be pure, just not have full rank!)

Comment: OK I think I see it now. The CHSH inequality is not meant to be applied to classical mechanics, but rather to a LHV model.

Answer (score 1):

In a certain sense, computing the expectation value of a quantum operator is equivalent to an average of measurement results on an ensemble state, which corresponds to the average over many runs of the classical game you consider for the CHSH scenario. Regarding the fact that the CHSH bound is violated only for certain states, that’s why you have a less or equal: only particular settings can show how quantum mechanics does not obey the CHSH inequality

Comment: Yeah but I understand that what you usually want is like “guessing” the output of quantum gates without knowing the input. So you look for the best strategy to guess right with highest probability (maybe I’m mistaken with this). If you need to know the state for the quantum gate to outperform a classical gate, what’s the point?